# Showing data in a JTextArea from another class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, class, jtextarea

I am making a simple interface which someone put data on the fields and later, when it pushes the "reservar" button, another class is open and show the data in a JTextArea. In the code below, I want to show the text: "prueba" but it doesn't work, what is the problem?
How can I show text in a JTextArea from another class?

Thank You!

```
private void botonReservarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
// TODO add your handling code here:
String nombre = "";
String telefono = "";
nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre de la persona de contacto: ");
telefono = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Número de teléfono: ");

setNombreApellidos(nombre);
setTelefono(telefono);
setTipoEvento(comboEvento.getSelectedItem().toString());
setFechaEvento(spinnerFecha.getValue().toString());
setNumPersonas(Integer.valueOf(spinnerPersonas.getValue().toString()));
setTipoCocina(comboCocina.getSelectedItem().toString());
setNumJornadas(Integer.valueOf(spinnerJornadas.getValue().toString()));
setNumHabitaciones(Integer.valueOf(spinnerHabitaciones.getValue().toString()));

ResumenReserva resumen = new ResumenReserva(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
JTextArea textAreaResumen = new JTextArea("Prueba");
textAreaResumen.setEditable(false);
resumen.setTextAreaResumen(textAreaResumen);
add(textAreaResumen);
resumen.setVisible(true);}
```

Comment: I just want to suggest you to write your code using English (variables, method names), so that others can better understand the purpose of your code.

Comment: Best to create and post a valid [mre]. Also, don't create a new text area here but rather give the class that holds the text area a setter method that allows outside classes to set the text displayed in its text area

Comment: *One* ```JFrame```  per app. You're making it too complex. You could even do ```JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, textAreaResumen)```I'm assuming you're really going to put more info in there as that component is otherwise overkill

Comment: From the code in your question: `add(textAreaResumen);` Shouldn't that be `resumen.add(textAreaResumen);` ? Also from the code in your question: `ResumenReserva resumen = new ResumenReserva(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);` If you want to open another window, consider using a `JDialog` rather than a `JFrame`.

Comment: I built another constructor with a javax.swing.JDialog and it seems to work. I didn't know that I have to use one JFrame per app. But, could you say me why? thanks to all of you!!

Comment: That will work, yes. It's just good practice to have only one frame per app. Oftentimes, under the hood, that window is special to the OS. You can get into difficulties and confusion with another ```JFrame``` with the app closing when you don't want it to, etc.